# Can I add hashes and a digital signature to a compressed file, and is it necessary in this situation?

Tags: integrity

I am wanting to create a project for a Linux Desktop environment and was curious about a certain subject. I plan to add all the files of the project and compress it into a `.zip` file. Is is possible for me to add `md5`, `sha1`, and `sha256` hashes to the `.zip` file? If possible how would I go about doing this. I would also like to add a digital signature too. Thanks!

Comment: Are you asking how to use `sha256sum` and co or how to use zip? Why are you not using the native package management?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open a Linux Terminal and `cd` into the directory with your project.

Type:

```
echo `md5sum <filename here>` > md5.txt
```

This will calculate the md5 hash of your file and put it in md5.txt

If you want to do the same with other hash algorithms you can use `sha1sum`, `sha256sum`, etc, in this same way. If you want to store a digital signature in a zip file just paste it into a text file.

I don't see why zipping should be a problem, it's just compressing the files, so now you can go ahead and zip up all the files you need, like that `md5.txt` file you just created.

To zip up files in terminal you can either:

```
zip archive.zip md5.txt file.php
```

Which will create a zip archive named `archive.zip` containing `md5.txt` and `file.php` (you can list as many files as you want to zip up).

Or you can run:

```
zip -r archive.zip folder/
```

Which will zip up the entire contents of the `folder/` folder